# How Should I print a pointer of a Char

Tags: c++, pointers

When using this code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char grade = 'A';
    char *pGrade = &grade;

    std::cout << pGrade;

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me a strange result like:

```
 A╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ÿ√∩
```

What should I do to make it give me a proper output?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Sorry for closing with an unrelated language. The rationale is the same though.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to output the pointer address is using [reinterpret_cast conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to `std::uintptr_t`, e.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    
    char grade = 'A';
    char *pGrade = &grade;
    
    std::cout << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pGrade) << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/castptr2uniptr
7fff6e3e8d1e
```

If I misinterpreted your question and you actually want to output the character `'A'` using the pointer, then simply dereference the pointer, e.g.

```
std::cout << *pGrade << '\n';
```

Which would result in `'A'` being output.

Comment: No need to cast `*pGrade`, it's already a `char`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should print it as a `void *`, which is just a generic pointer. `std::cout` assumes that `char *` are null-terminated strings, so if you print a pointer to a character rather than a string, it will keep printing until it reaches a null byte. By using `void *`, you're making sure that there will be no confusion.

```cpp
char c = 'A';
std::cout << (void *)&c;
```

Output:

```
0x7ffcf2013567
```

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the `operator<<` overload that takes a **null-terminated** `char*` string as input. But your data is not null-terminated, which causes [**undefined behavior**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You are seeing extra garbage in the output because the `operator<<` is printing surrounding memory that follows the `grade` variable until it encounters a `0x00` byte.  But it could just have easily have crashed your code instead, or corrupted memory, or done just about anything else.  That is the nature of *undefined behavior*.

If you want to print the memory address that the pointer is pointing at, then use the `operator<<` overload that takes a `void*`:

```
int main()
{
    char grade = 'A';
    char *pGrade = &grade;
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(pGrade);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are expecting just the `A` to be printed by itself, then use the `operator<<` overload that takes a single `char`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char grade = 'A';
    char *pGrade = &grade;
    std::cout << *pGrade;
    return 0;
}
```

Or, use `cout.write()`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char grade = 'A';
    char *pGrade = &grade;
    std::cout.write(pGrade, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, null-terminate your data:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char grade[2] = {'A', '\0'};
    char *pGrade = grade;
    std::cout << pGrade;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a proper pointer.  However, in C, a `char *` is always assumed to be a zero-terminated string.  The `cout` formatter thus prints everything up through the next zero byte.  Notice your "A" at the beginning?

If you want to see the numeric value of the pointer for some reason, you'll have to cast it to (uint64_t), and you'll probably want to print it in hex:

```
    std::cout << std::hex << (uint64_t)pGrade << "\n";
```